# only one thread executes the cuda kernel

Tags: c++, cuda

I am new to GPU programming and specifically CUDA/C++. I have written a simple code just to use `atomicAdd` to increase all members of an array by 1.

But the result shows just the first element of the array increased and others stay the same. My code is as follows.

Thanks for any help in advance.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
__global__ void Histcount( int *a)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    {
        atomicAdd(&a[i], 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int * hostarray = new int[20];
    int * devarray;
    cudaError_t error;
    error=cudaMalloc(&devarray, sizeof(int) * 20);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        hostarray[i] = i ;
    }
    cudaMemcpy((int *)devarray, (int *)hostarray, sizeof(int) * 20, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    dim3 gs = (1, 1);
    dim3 bs = (20, 1, 1);
    Histcount <<<gs, bs >>>  (devarray);
    cudaMemcpy((int *)hostarray, (int *)devarray, sizeof(int) * 20, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cout << hostarray[i]<<endl;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a valid way to specify `dim3` variables:

```
dim3 gs = (1, 1);
dim3 bs = (20, 1, 1);
```

In fact, the compiler may be throwing warnings on those lines, and if so you should not ignore those.

You should do either:

```
dim3 gs = dim3(1, 1);
dim3 bs = dim3(20, 1, 1);
```

or:

```
dim3 gs(1, 1);
dim3 bs(20, 1, 1);
```

The problem with your implementation is that the compiler doesn't know your actual intent with for example:

```
(20, 1, 1)
```

By itself as you have it, the compiler (may issue a warning and in fact) [evaluates that expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) to be `1`, which it then assigns as a scalar to your `dim3` variable.  So you end up with a block size of 1 and a grid size of 1 (which was not your intent), and your code ran only 1 thread overall.

Comment: For details as to why (20, 1, 1)  evaluates to 1, look up "comma operator" in a C or C++ reference. The comma operator returns the value of the rightmost expression, which is 1 in this case.

Comment: [The expression on the left is also evaluated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), then that result is discarded.  Apparently, the compiler will (may?) throw a warning if the expression on the left is a constant value.  Evaluating it has no effect, therefore the (my) compiler issues a warning "expression has no effect".    If I replace this with some expression with side effects, e.g. `(j++, j++, 1)` then the warnings disappear (although the final result is still the unintended scalar 1).

Comment: I think warnings are always in the "may" category, because they are not mandated by the C/C++ language standards, best I recall.

Comment: I think you are right as usual.  Anyway I've updated my answer slightly.  Thanks for the pointer on comma operator.